# Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory "/app/views"

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, handlebars.js

I just created my first node.js app with Express. I'm using Handlebars as my view engine.

Everything is working fine on my local machine. However, as soon as I push the code to Heroku, I get the following error in the Heoku logs.

> Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory "/app/views"

This is a part of my listing and the file structure. it **fails** on `res.render("login");`

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("login");
});

app.listen(port);
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is the log from Heroku

```
2019-11-12T18:38:42.240873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-11-12T18:38:43.043841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mygalleryassignment.herokuapp.com request_id=66e3bcd7-8fc9-4e4f-aec2-abf6fda00a03 fwd="66.209.62.22" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046317+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory "/app/views"
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046480+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046491+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046494+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/server.js:51:7
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046497+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046499+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046501+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046503+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046506+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046508+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2019-11-12T18:38:43.046510+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `path` to set the directory path to views like: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))`? If it's truly at the root of your app's directory structure, you shouldn't need that.

I think you can just remove that line altogether. I'm not sure why, locally it works, but everything else you got appears like it should work.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I used as my "tester" for your situation. This code works both locally and when deployed to Heroku. Not sure this is super enlightenting since it is pretty close to original example code.

I've also included my directory structure.

server.js

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("login");
});

app.listen(port);
```

[image: my directory structure]

Comment: Interesting because I was able to successfully deploy the exact copy of your server js with some views that mimic your set up and can visit at the heroku url. The only thing I changed was replaced `bodyParser` with `express`.

Comment: Wow, Sorry what do you mean by changing `bodyParser` with `express`?
Can you please post the latest version that worked for you? It would be really helpful if you post your `package.json` as well just in case

Comment: Your code would work if you included the requre('body-parser') which is part of express. Me using express directly is just a more verbose way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I added the log from heroku. I'm not sure if I've done something wrong on the Heoku side. But it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Can you please upload your code somewhere so I can compare it with mine. It's driving me crazy. the same code doesn't work for me. Really appreciate it

Comment: Here's a repo link: https://github.com/bgaynor78/demo-express-handlebars

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'));`

you were missing the `/` in front of public

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for your help. I tried that. Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: Can you post your public directory? If its only working locally my next guess is that your login route is changed when you push to production.

Comment: Tom, I'm not sure if I understood it correctly but I updated the image and expanded the public folder in it